# How to Configure services in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, quartz.net

I am using .NET 6.0, and I am using Quartz.Net to schedule a event at a specific time.

I am using this: [Tutorial](https://www.thecodehubs.com/using-quartz-scheduler-in-asp-net-core/)

But in the end I need to configure in startup class inside the `ConfigureServices` method - like this:

```
// Add Quartz services
services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();

// Add our job
services.AddSingleton<RemindersJob>();
services.AddSingleton(new JobSchedule(
    jobType: typeof(RemindersJob),
    cronExpression: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *")); // run every 5 min
```

But the `startup` class is not there in my project, so how should I configure this?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you would use the official integration package: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are looking at is probably .NET Core 5.
In .NET 6 you need to configure in Program.cs and change this:

```
services.AddScoped<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
services.AddScoped<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
```

insted of this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure in Program.cs